# Relative path for annotation processor in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, google-app-engine, build

I have a AppEngine connected Android Project, the .factrypath file of the project looks like

```
<factorypath>
<factorypathentry kind="VARJAR" 
id="ECLIPSE_HOME/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_2.4.0.v201205091048-rel-r37/gwt-      
2.4.0/requestfactory-apt.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
<factorypathentry kind="EXTJAR" id="/home/vince/git/requestfactory-apt-2.4.0.jar" 
enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

Though I am using variable `ECLIPSE_HOME`. Can a path be given so that when the project is fetched where gwt-2.4.0 folder is changed to some other version, it will still work.?

I saw kind="plugin" and org.eclipse something for annotation.. Can something similar be done for this to replace the almost absolute path given above? Maybe wildcard * can also be used, but I could not get it to work on Linux..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I saw kind="plugin" and org.eclipse something for annotation.. 
>   Can something similar be done for this to replace the almost 
>   absolute path given above?

Yes. There is an API that a plugin writer can use to contribute annotation processors straight from the plugin without resorting to what you see above. There isn't anything you can do as an end user to improve this. You should file a bug report for Google.